# Where is 'webgl.osmesalib' parameter?

Tags: firefox, graphics, webgl

I'm trying to get webgl running on my firefox (v37.0.2) via software acceleration with mesa. I tried following the steps that have been stated in this article:
http://www.binarytides.com/enable-webgl-firefox-ubuntu/

However, I am unable to find any parameter named '*webgl.osmesalib*' in **about:config** section? Has this been removed (or renamed)? If yes, then how should I instruct firefox to use  mesa's software acceleration for webGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like support for OSMesa was [removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=743755) in favour LLVMpipe.